# Apache - Invalid Command 'Auth' error 500

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to implement pass directory authentication using:

```
Auth Name "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

It's 100% correct.

Seems like issue lies in apache modules?

I'm using Apache2 and Ubuntu 13.04

Gives me error:

```
[Wed Sep 11 22:40:07 2013] [alert] [client xxx.xx.xxx.xx]     /home/somebody/public_html/somewebsite/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Auth', perhaps     misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `AuthName` instead `Auth Name`.

Apache documentation for [`AuthName Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authname).